# How to debug the following Python code؟؟؟؟

Tags: python

Hello to all programmers
In the code below, in the hack class, two variables, name and number, cause problems and give the following error. How can I solve it??
Thanks

```
TypeError: hack.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

```
import os
os.system('cls')

class test :
    def __init__(self, name ,number):
        self.name=name
        self.number=number

    def add(self):
        return f' I am a  {self.name}  my love  program'

class hack (test):
    def __init__ (self,year):
       super().__init__(name , number)
       self.year=year

p=hack('mahdi',19)
print(p.add())
```

Comment: `self` is an implicit argument to `__init__`, therefore only a value for `year` is expected.

Comment: It looks like `hack.__init__` should be defined with three arguments (plus `self`):  `name`, `number`, and `year`.  It then needs to be called with three arguments.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you wrote `p=hack('mahdi',19)`, however, you didn't include the `name` variable in the `__init__(self, year)` definition. The following should work:

```
class hack (test):
    def __init__ (self, name, number, year):
       super().__init__(name , number)
       self.year=year
```